# How to avoid website overloading (error 503) if user keeps clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, asp.net, mod-rewrite

Help! Noticed if my website links (any link) are kept clicked continuously, my website stops with error 503. Website shuts down or slows down for few minutes.

Please help, its a dangerous thing to happen to any website , regarding performance and safety.

Comment: what exactly your links do, do they post data, just redirects to new page, etc??

Comment: I mean, there can be something my website is lacking, that's why It's specific to mine. I tried clicking like this on other websites, but they worked just fine. So any tips or help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Those links are pages to song lyrics, which fetch the data from mysql and show on that page. Used link beautifier for those pages though.

Comment: Who's hosting your website and what are the specs of the server hosting it?

Comment: @Callam you cant do anything with those specs. there is a huge missconfiguration / bad code, and its hard to find that without seeing it :)

Comment: maybe something on backend/DB side, open connections, low response time

Comment: Godaddy Delux Hosting, I had  chats with them, they said nothing wrong their side. So I am here for getting some help if I can.

Comment: Normallt pages used to open within 2-3 seconds, but now taking more than 15 seconds/page... High latency

Comment: plz make sure you are closing connections after request completes

Comment: Actually it's based on PDO mysqli, so the connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To close the connection,PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

Comment: Unclear and too broad. Code audit, logging, caching, app firewall, etc. are all possible steps to mitigate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

503 is a code for "Service Unavailable"--which is an understandable response from a server that is currently overloaded with requests.

It is not dangerous *per se*, but many webservers or preprocessors are misconfigured to output debugging information on 503 pages. I wouldn't worry about the 503 itself, just the information on the 503 error page.

Comment: oh, so if a service goes down after ~10 requests / s it  is okay?!

Comment: exactly Jonas! My website service is going down again and again whole day! guessing some competitor website is doing the to my website. Already lost more than 50% customers this week..

Comment: @JonasW. No, I would definitely not say that is okay, but it's not dangerous (which is what was asked). However, fixing this is a large problem that depends on everything from your code down to your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service) attacks, then you will many many options. The first consideration is the amount of control you have over the traffic. Are you able to enable firewalls? DDoS protection such as emergency IP black lists?

Usually your service provide and provided your website have options, contact them. If they don't, then switch providers. If you are using some sort of PaaS or IaaS solution such as [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) or [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/), then you have the basic protection of the service provider (Google's infrastructure) and also your own settings depending on the product you choose.

As far as design / code is concerned, you can always have [captcha](https://www.a2hosting.com/blog/implement-captcha-solution-website/) implemented to tell legit human traffic from DDoS automated traffic. That way you can setup a page that only reroutes legit traffic to your real website.

Ultimately, if you don't know how to deal with DDoS, it's best to use a service that provides that for you.